# How to correctly update a specific jQuery package inside Kendo

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have been tasked with updating a few different packages in our code base. This one has me confused.

jquery 1.9.1 --- CompanyName/Web/Administration/Scripts/kendo/jquery.min.js

When I check our jquery nuget package, it is up to date. It looks like this file specifically is out of date and I am unsure how to update it.

Can I update this specifically using the command line and npm? If so, how can I find this specific package to update it with npm? Or is there another way to update this? Do I have to update Kendo in order to get the jquery package inside of it updated?

Here is a photo of the file for reference (It is a lot of code that I do not think is necessary for the question):

[image]

I am unsure if this question is even properly worded, I am a bit out of my depth here. Please provide any feedback necessary so I can improve on my question.

Answer (score 0):

In order to update specific script files, you can make use of [Kendo CDN](https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/).

This resource allows you to find specific scripts based on the version of Kendo you are using. In order to update the vulnerable `jquery.min.js` package, I needed to navigate to: **[https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/[VERSION]/js/FILENAME.min.js](https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/%5BVERSION%5D/js/FILENAME.min.js)**

The difficult part was hunting down the compatible version with my solution. This resource was helpful in that regard: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/supporting/jquery-support.

When I found the version in my solution, and the compatible versions of `jquery.min.js`, I simply copied and pasted the code into my solution, built, and ran. Everything worked fine, and nothing broke.